# I am just trying to accept my android sdk licenses but it shows me this error of having java home variable not set

Tags: android, flutter

[As soon as i try to accept my licenses for android , it gives me this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObvVc.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set your JAVA_HOME path in Windows PATH? I've found this useful tutorial assuming you're on windows 10:
https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-set-java_home-on-windows-10/